# iOS Screenreader ( Voiceover ) focus removed element in dom

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I am trying to make my app accessibility. In my case I need sometimes to remove some buttons from the dom.

For example:

```
<div id="content">
<button id="button1" tabIndex="1" ... />
<button id="button2" tabIndex="2" ... /></div>
```

I now want to remove the button2 and do something like :

```
document.getElement('content').removeChild( <element button2> )
```

This works well, but the screenreader ( Voiceover ) on ios will continue focusing this element . Asso if it does not exist anymore. It always reads the content from button2 but I cannot switch to the other buttons. I need to tap on the screen to focus on another element.

Is there a way to retrigger the Screenreader? or to update the div area from ios Screenreader?

Comment: At which moment are you removing the element? Does the issue occur if you remove the element while it has focus, or even independent of that?

Comment: Why is the code example for removal not valid javascript? If you can observe the issue, there should be working code, right? it would be `document.getElementById('content').removeChild(document.getElementById('button2'));`
Please try to provide a working code snippet in your question to make the issue reproducible.

Comment: Never remove the currently focused element from the DOM. If you need to do it, first move the focus elsewhere before removing the element.